# relenium package: failed to create firefoxClass instance

Tags: r, selenium

I am trying to use [relenium package](http://lluisramon.github.io/relenium) to scrape some web content. So I installed packages as required in the documentation

```
install.packages("rJava")
require(devtools)

install_github('seleniumJars', 'LluisRamon')
install_github('relenium', 'LluisRamon')
```

loaded packages (I probably did not need the first two; I tried with and without with the same result

```
#require(rJava)
#require(seleniumJars)
require(relenium)
```

When I am trying to instantiate firefox browser class

```
firefox <- firefoxClass$new()
```

I am getting the following error message

```
`Error in exceptionTable[, 1] : subscript out of bounds`
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I had this problem when I first installed relenium.  Restarting R fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I first installed relenium. Restarting R fixed the problem.  But, it recently resurfaced when I updated Firefox to the latest version.  I uninstalled Firefox and went back to version 31, and the problem went away.

Relenium is no longer under active development.